# How to update HTML after page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a script that takes text from a hidden div: 
`var content = column.find(".hidden").text().split('');`, and splices it with random 1s and 0s to give a decryption effect. The script writes to another div: `column.children(".code").text(content);`

So I'm ripping text from .hidden, turning it into an array, splicing it (within `setInterval()` so it's animated) with a binary array, and putting it into a visible div. The problem here is I can't get any HTML inside the visible div, so I can't include linebreaks or any other useful things. I tried using `.html()` instead of `.text()`, but then it puts html into the visible div, instead of actually formatting the page with it. I tried to `.append()` the changes, but it never even showed up because I probably did it wrong. I was told I may be able to do this through node manipulation, but nothing I tried worked.

So the question is: How can I update the DOM so it shows the final HTML, change the text without destroying the html, insert properly formated HTML at the end, or some other solution I can't think of because I have no idea what I'm doing.

Edit: Here is a relevant fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/13t31w5p/

Comment: Can you post what you tried?

Comment: `can't get html in a div` makes no sense on face value. Without some sample of what you are trying to do this question is far too vague to do anything with. Provide some samples and a demo in a code sandbox would really help

Comment: I added a fiddle to provide more detail.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax to add content to an existing element is:

```
/**
 * .append()
 * {@link http://api.jquery.com/append/}
 */
$('div.mydiv').append('this text will be added at the end of the div. ')
```

Note that the [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) and [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) methods are more or less "conversion" scripts that manipulate existing content. Click the links to read more about them.

If this doesn't answer your question, please provide a bit more of a verbose example of what you're doing -- perhaps you could include the relevant code snippets and put them in something like [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [Gist](http://gist.github.com/).